# Relative path of file to the php include path with htaccess

Tags: php, css, apache, .htaccess

I have `root/index.php`. Inside index.php I have `<?php include __DIR__.'../site/index.php'; ?>`

The root of the domain `example.com` is `root` directory.

When I access `example.com/style.css` I get 404 file not found, because the `style.css` is in `site` directory not in `root` directory.

**How can I look for the files inside `site` directory instead `root` directory with htaccess?**

Other suggestions are welcomed.

**EDIT:**

The directories `root` and `site` are siblings.

Comment: Your question is a little confusing. Are the `root` and `site` directories siblings? Or, is the `site` directory inside `root`? You mention `.htaccess` but have not posted any example of what you have so far - please provide more information. :-)

Comment: Where you have placed your `.htaccess` file? Also you mean you want to map to the **site** directory instead of **root**

Comment: htaccess is in `root`. Yes I want to map to `site` directory instead of `root` directory.

Comment: Look at my solution now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The domains `s1.com`, `s2.com` point to `root` directory. `s1.com` gets its files from `site1`, `s2.com` gets its files from `site2`.

Structue:

```
├── root
│   └── index.php
|   └── .htaccess
├── site
|   └── *
├── site1
|   └── *
└── site2
    └── *
```

.htaccess (in `root`):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

php(`index.php` in in `root`):

```
<?php
$paths = array(
    's1.com' => __DIR__ . '/../site1',
    's2.com' => __DIR__ . '/../site2'
);
$path = isset($paths[$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']]) ? $paths[$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']] : __DIR__ . '/../qioqia.com/site';
if (array_filter(explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']))) {
    $request = str_replace(strrchr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '?'), "", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    $ext = strrchr( $request, '.');
    if ($ext === false) include $path . '/index.php';
    else {
        $mimes = array(
            '.jpg' => 'image/jpeg',
            '.css' => 'text/css',
            '.js' => 'application/javascript',
            '.ico' => 'image/x-icon'
        );
        $mime = isset($mimes[$ext]) ? $mimes[$ext] : 'application/octet-stream';
        header('Content-Type: ' . $mime);
        echo file_get_contents($path . $request);
    }
} else include $path . '/index.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is not possible with `.htaccess`. However, you can include things belong the web root with PHP, as you have done with your `index.php` file.

**Layout** (from what I can gather).

```
.
├── root
│   └── index.php
└── site
    └── index.php
    └── style.css
```

You could use `.htaccess` to point all requests at `/root/index.php`, and then either `include` them or use `file_get_contents` or similar to output them from `/site`.

Whilst I can understand serving PHP files from below the web root, why are you doing this for CSS? You may want to rethink your directory structure, and place web assets such as javascript and stylesheets above the web root.

Comment: The all thing is an old curiosity of mine. If i point `example.com` to `site` directory everything works fine. But if I point `example.com` to `root` directory all the files that are in `site` will give 404.